# Can't step into a function in debugging: The Mocrosoft visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor does not appear to be running on the remote computer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, xaml

I have been given an application to work on, a simple job to update a function. However, I am unable to use the debugger to step through the code to edit the function

When the search button is clicked on the main menu, the program runs fine and I can step through everything with the debugger, until I reach this function:

```vb
Private Function ftnCompetitionSearch(Optional ByVal pstrCompNum As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal pstrCompYear As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal pstrCompTypeId As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal pstrBranchId As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal pstrPositionId As String = Nothing) As svcHR.Competitions()
    Dim listComp As svcHR.Competitions() = Nothing
    Dim myClient As svcHR.IsvcHRClient = Nothing
    Try
        'Perform search and display results in datagrid'

        myClient = New svcHR.IsvcHRClient
        listComp = myClient.ftnSearchCompetitions(pstrCompNum, pstrCompYear, pstrCompTypeId, pstrBranchId, Nothing, pstrPositionId)

        Return listComp
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        If myClient IsNot Nothing Then myClient.Close()
    End Try
End Function


'This then flows to a file called Reference.vb where this function exists:'

Public Function ftnSearchCompetitions(ByVal pstrCompNum As String, ByVal pstrCompYear As String, ByVal pstrCompTypeId As String, ByVal pstrBranchId As String, ByVal pstrLocationId As String, ByVal pstrPosTypeId As String) As svcHR.Competitions() Implements svcHR.IsvcHR.ftnSearchCompetitions
            Return MyBase.Channel.ftnSearchCompetitions(pstrCompNum, pstrCompYear, pstrCompTypeId, pstrBranchId, pstrLocationId, pstrPosTypeId)
End Function
```

The line `listComp = myClient.ftnSearchCompetitions(pstrCompNum, pstrCompYear, pstrCompTypeId, pstrBranchId, Nothing, pstrPositionId)` is what calls the search method that populates the main menu with the search results. This is the function I’ll need to update, however if I try to step into it using the debugger,  I get this error message:

> "Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine 'machinenameexample.ca' failed. The Microsoft visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging."

This message is also shown if I try to step into the `MyBase.Channel` line.

I've tried running MSVSMON on my computer, but it didn't change anything. I've done some research into it and I haven't found any straightforward solutions to this, although it seems to be a rather popular problem.

Comment: Where is the source code you expect to use to debug that function? BTW your `Catch` does more harm than good - when you catch ex then throw ex you lose your stack trace, and your caller is going to see the exception anyway so just remove the `Catch`. You really just need only the `Try...Finally` so you can close your client.

Comment: I just need to follow the program through to get to that function in order to edit it. I use the debugger to do this. I'm not sure what the source code you're asking for is. Also, thanks for the heads up about the ```try-catch```

Comment: `... get to that function in order to edit it ... not sure what the source code you're asking for is ...`. I'm asking about the source code for that function. You seem to want to edit it but if you don't know where the source code is how can you edit it? From what I can tell, it's an instance function of this class `svcHR.IsvcHRClient`. Do you have the code for that class or just a reference? It appears that you don't have the code.

Comment: I've edited the question. There is a file called Reference.vb in the IsvcHRClient which has this function, but I still can't step into it to get to the location of the source code, something which I've come to rely on heavily for editing code. I follow the progression of the program to get to the specific function I want to edit.

Comment: I've got it. It turns out I was a bit lax in my sleuthing for the function. I have found the source code, and I'm going to work through it. Thanks for your replies though.

Comment: So what was the problem?

Comment: I rely on stepping through the debugger to find out which methods are being used (the application I'm working on was made by someone else, and as is typical, its a mess of seemingly identical code snippets that have no documentation). In order to find out which methods I need to update, I wanted to step through the application using the debugger. I ran into this error when I tried to do that, and I was hoping for an easy fix. I've been told that I simply have a bad connection string, as in I'm pointing to the wrong database. That's all.

Comment: As of now I haven't fixed it, but if I do I'll post an answer here for anyone else.

Comment: Your question is about not being able to step into a function, but if you don't have the source and the function is either in an assembly with no pdb or it is on a server without remote debugging (and no source) then it's impossible to debug it. Then there is no solution to your problem

Comment: I found the problem / solution and posted it as an answer. A bit of a journey, but I got there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a bad client endpoint address in the app.config file. The default was pointing to a remote computer, which was inactive. The solution is to instead point to the localhost.

Before:

```
<client>
            <endpoint address="http://exampleWebsiteThatICan'tAccess.ca/thingIWant"
                behaviorConfiguration="LargeEndpointBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IwcfCommonFunctions"
                contract="svcCommonFunctions.IwcfCommonFunctions" name="BasicHttpBinding_IwcfCommonFunctions" />
            <endpoint address="http://exampleWebsiteThatICan'tAccess.ca/thingIWant"
                behaviorConfiguration="LargeEndpointBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IsvcHR" contract="svcHR.IsvcHR"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IsvcHR">
                <identity>
                    <dns />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
</client>
```

After:

```
<client>
            <endpoint address="http://exampleWebsiteThatICan'tAccess.ca/thingIWant"
                behaviorConfiguration="LargeEndpointBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IwcfCommonFunctions"
                contract="svcCommonFunctions.IwcfCommonFunctions" name="BasicHttpBinding_IwcfCommonFunctions" />
            **<endpoint address="http://localhost:50012/thingIWant"**
                behaviorConfiguration="LargeEndpointBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IsvcHR" contract="svcHR.IsvcHR"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IsvcHR">
                <identity>
                    <dns />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
</client>
```

I changed the second service endpoint to point to my local system instead of the remote computer.

To get my localhost http:// I opened the project that has a web.config file by right clicking and viewing it in Google chrome, then copying the url into the endpoint.